# Why I see only my MySite?

Tags: 2010

In the SiteCollection when I call `http://abc/sites/abc/_layouts/userdisp.aspx`?ID=1 SharePoint redirects me to my MySite. (`http://abc/my/Person.aspx?accountname=...`)

But if I call this page for another user e.g.

```
http://abc/sites/abc/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=12
```

SharePoint do not redirects me to the Users MySite but to

```
http://abc/sites/abc/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=12&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fabc%2Fsites%2Fabc%2F%5Flayouts%2Fuserdisp%2Easpx%3FMembershipGroupId%3D0%26FilterField1%3DContentType%26FilterValue1%3DPerson
```

Why is this so? Can I avoid/correct this behavior?

Comment: how you calling this page just click on withint site colelction or direclty put in browser or any app?

Answer (score 0):

Here are scenarios.

- If you directly type  this
  url(`http://abc/sites/abc/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=1`) in browser
  then it will redirect you
  `(http://abc/my/Person.aspx?accountname=') + source of the link( which is site collection from where you are calling)
- If you want to access the mysite of other users you can directly " `http://mysite/personal/username`'